# save file to sd card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

How can I listen to the name of the button that was pressed when saving a file to sd card i have many different buttons and one method

```
File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"/Download/Alnabi.pdf");
```

If a person clicks the button number one i want the alnabi.pdf to be saved to sd card , but what if i clicked the second button ? i want a way to change the file name "alnabi.pdf" to another one depending on which button was clicked, thank you.

Comment: That is not valid JavaScript syntax. Are you talking about Java instead?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide different functionality for both buttons. But to keep the code maintainable I would recommend to reuse the code, that is common for all/both buttons (by defining a method).

The code could look something like:

```
button1.addActionListener(e -> saveFile("Alnabi.pdf")); // Java8-Syntax   
button2.addActionListener(e -> saveFile("AnotherOne.pdf"));
```

And the method, containing the common code:

```
public void saveFile(String variableFileName) {
    File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"/Download/"+variableFileName);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first write a code that checks if external storage is available for READ / WRITE operations
 Method to check if user has permissions to write on external storage or not

```
public static boolean canWriteOnExternalStorage() {
// get the state of your external storage
 String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
// if storage is mounted return true
  Log.v(“sTag”, “Yes, can write to external storage.”);
  return true;
 }
return false;
}
```

use this code to save file

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath() + “/your-dir-name/”);
dir.mkdir();
File file = new File(dir, “My-File-Name.txt”);
FileOutputStream os = outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
String data = “This is the content of my file”;
os.write(data.getBytes());
os.close();
```

need the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE” />
```